# Is randomInts suffering from ping-pong effect?

Tags: haskell, random

The below two code are taken from the RWH book's concurrency chapter:

```
force :: [a] -> ()
force xs = go xs `pseq` ()
    where go (_:xs) = go xs
          go [] = 1

randomInts :: Int -> StdGen -> [Int]
randomInts k g = let result = take k (randoms g)
                 in force result `seq` result
```

`randomInts` is a function for generating list of random number for testing the performance of parallel sorting algorithm. It has been mentioned in the book that they have avoided some potential problem in the above code. This is what has been said in the book:

> Invisible data dependencies.
>
> When we generate the list of random numbers, simply printing the
>   length of the list would not perform enough evaluation. This wouls
>   evaluate the spine of the list, but not its elements. The actual
>   random numbers would not be evaluated until the sort compares them.
>
> This can have serious consequences for performance. The value of a
>   random number depends on the value of the preceding random number in
>   the list, but we have scattered the list elements randomly among our
>   processor cores. If we did not evaluate the list elements prior to
>   sorting, we would suffer a terrible “ping pong” effect: not only would
>   evaluation bounce from one core to another, performance would suffer.
>
> Try snipping out the application of force from the body of main above:
>   you should find that the parallel code can easily end up three times
>   slower than the non-parallel code.

So basically they are saying that by using the `force` function they have avoided the ping-pong problem. But again during the explanation of the `force` function, they describe it like this:

> Notice that we don't care what's in the list; we walk down its spine
>   to the end, then use pseq once. There is clearly no magic involved
>   here: we are just using our usual understanding of Haskell's
>   evaluation model. And because we will be using force on the left hand
>   side of par or pseq, we don't need to return a meaningful value.

As seen from the definition of the `force` function and the explanation above, the elements in the individual list elements are not evaluated. So how does the `randomInts` function is actually avoiding the `ping-pong` effect. Is this an error in the book or am I understanding something wrong ?

Comment: I would say it is an error in the book. (Oh yes, quick pro tip. Instead of using a force function, or even `Control.DeepSeq.force`, you can just do the sort twice, timing the second run. By making sure the list is memorized, but not the sort, it is a simple way to make sure everything that needs evaluated is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`randomInts` actually doesn't seem to suffer from `ping-pong` effect.  The function `force` is actually not only traversing the entire spline of the list, but also evaluating the elements of the list.

```
import Control.Parallel (par, pseq)

force :: [a] -> ()
force xs = go xs `pseq` ()
  where go (_:xs) = go xs
        go [] = 1
```

In ghci:

```
ghci > let a = [1..10]
ghci > :sprint a
a = _
ghci > force a
()
ghci > :sprint a
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

So the `force` function fully evaluates the list, saving it from the ping-pong effect.